# How to change value of comma in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I change the default value of the `,` in the following code so that it does not insert a space

```
gas = int(input("How much have you spent on gas? "))
electric = int(input("How much have you spent on electric? "))
onlinePurchases = int(input("How much have you spent on online purchases? "))
total = gas + electric + onlinePurchases

print("Monthly Total: $", total)
```

The current code would print:

```
"Monthly total: $ *total*"
```

Is there a way to make it print:

```
"Monthly total: $*total*"
```

I do not want a space between the dollar sign and the amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From python `print` [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

So you would want

```
print("Monthly Total: $", total, sep='')
```

Changing `sep` (separator) from a space to an empty string

Comment: Thank you and just so i know is "sep" short for "separation" and if not what does it stand for?

Answer (score 3):

`print("Monthly Total: ${0}".format(total))`

or

`print("Monthly Total: $%d" % total)`